# Should I have lied about not picking up trash on my break?

Tags: interviewing, ethics

**I was asked in a group interview for a service-sector job whether I would pick up trash on the company's lawn if I randomly walked past it on my lunch break of my own initiative. I indicated that I wouldn't, because that's the truth. Should I have lied and responded with yes?**

---

When I was 17, I was applying for a popular job at a large amusement park in Norway. There was such a vast amount of applicants that the company chose to filter us out using group evaluation exercises. We were put into groups and asked to solve certain problems together, and the interviewers would observe us, deciding who to select for real interviews. Those of us who eventually got employed would be operating rides, serving food, helping customers, selling tickets, etc.

They also asked us yes or no questions in plural. We had to raise our hands to say yes or no. One of the questions that I remember very clearly was:

> You have just finished the first half of your day, and are on your way to lunch. Walking through the park, you notice that there is some trash on the grass next to the road. If you pick it up and put it in a trash can, raise your hand. If you ignore it and continue to lunch, keep your hand down.

There were dozens of people there, and I think I might have been the only one who kept my hand down. The vast majority raised their hands.

The reason I didn't is because honestly, I wouldn't pick it up. And I don't believe most of those who raised their hands would, either. I felt that both the interviewers and much of the crowd knew that. I'm not against white lies, but this one just felt too blatant to me. Like I would be sucking up to the interviewers, and we would both know it. I guess I did it a little bit out of defiance. But I also felt there was a chance it was a test question to check the honesty of applicants. Or that, at least, the interviewers would appreciate the honesty. (Some of the jobs involve money and other things that are partly based on trust.)

As for why I wouldn't pick up the trash: I would do it if specifically or generally instructed to do so by my superiors. But I would not take the initiative to do it myself. it's not my job, somebody else are employed to do it. It's my lunch time. The trash may be unhygienic to touch, risk staining my uniform, etc. What if my job was related to food? (A lot of them are.) How would the guests like it if they saw a food worker handling old trash from the roadside?

**Should I have lied here, and raised my hand?**

I will reveal later whether I was selected for a private interview or not.

Comment: If they wanted to know whether you knew the "right" answer, they could have asked "Should you pick it up?" or "Would an ideal employee pick it up?".

Comment: The interviewers might appreciate the honesty, but still prefer a chance of getting a possibly lying employee who might do the right thing over an honest employee who definitely won't do the right thing. Also, I think this is rather opinion based; whether or not you should lie depends on your own goals and motivations, I doubt there's an objective answer.

Comment: @Erik Maybe the problem is that I didn't even believe picking up the trash was the right thing to do? That's not my job, someone else is employed to do that. It's my lunch time. The trash may be unhygienic to touch, stain my uniform, etc. What if my job was related to food? (A lot of them are.) How would the guests like it if they saw a food worker handling trash? I might have alerted the people employed to keep the park clean.

Comment: @Erik  As for opinion based: I wonder if it's quite common for questions involving ethics to evoke opinions to some degree or the other?As for my goal, it was to get the job, but also to maintain my personal integrity.

Comment: Not worth a full answer but I'd add *never* rebel against the interview process. I admit I have no idea what they are thinking to do with these answers, but they probably think their process is great and better to not challenge them on that while going through it.

Comment: This sounds like one of those questions bad HR departments ask to suss out a candidate's moral/ethical positions, but actually serve to strongly select for sociopaths and/or Machiavellian candidates.  Probably not an employer you actually want to work for, unless you want to be surrounded by a mix of rule Nazis and lying backstabbers.

Comment: I think what this question is really getting at is not just about trash, but whether you would walk past something that was obviously wrong with the park and ignore it. In an amusement park, with lots of potentially dangerous rides and potential safety hazards for kids, it stands to reason that it is important to have employees who are alert and looking out for the condition of the park at all times, not to mention that management may place a high importance on cleanliness. Your no answer may be honest, but volunteering "it's not my job" so I'll ignore a problem is unlikely to get you any job.

Comment: @HopelessN00b LOL, I enjoyed this comment. Pretty much what my 16 year old self felt at the time, and what lead me to not raise my hand.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Keep in mind that this is about student jobs in a service industry. Bad hiring practices are pretty much a given. Group interviews also wouldn't fly in an office setting for instance.

Comment: I agree I wouldn't honestly pick up the trash. It's gross and you shouldn't perform job duties at lunch (mandated by US federal law!) So I think the fact they even asked this question, expecting "yes", means there's no reason to take the interview seriously. Since it's a game now, go ahead and raise your hand to proclaim "yes, in an ideal world, we'd all pick up trash" since that's what they're really asking.

Comment: @Lilienthal Oh well, my question is on hold now. Seems weird, I've seen plenty of questions like this here.

Comment: "You have just finished the first half of your day, and are on your way to lunch." - did you punch out for lunch already? Or are you still on the clock?

Comment: @WorkerDrone I would assume your lunch break has officially started the moment you leave your post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I was your age, I would also never pick up random trash around a building even if I was at school or at work.

Now I do pick up random trash items pretty much anywhere if it means I'm not going out of my way too much for it and there is a trash can nearby. (And to answer Paparazzi's question, no, I won't pick up cigarette butts unless they're directly in front of my home, but generally at other locations I only pick up the more obvious trash items).

What has changed? I am not really sure. It's not guilt. I certainly don't feel more guilty than when I was a teenager. Part of it is a feeling of ownership and part of it is habit I think since I didn't start doing these kind of things until I had been working a few years.

That being said, back to your question, yes, I do think you should have lied.

Fake it until you make it. Or so, the saying goes (assuming you really did want the job instead of letting the recruitment staff make that decision for you).

Also customer service at an amusement park does mean that management might require you to lie at some point. At Disneyland in Los Angeles for instance, whenever a ride broke down, and there was no ETA on the repair time, a friend of mine who worked there was only ever allowed to tell customers that the ride would be back up in 15 minutes, which irritated my friend to no end. She didn't want to lie to customers, she felt the policy was counter-productive, but she had to suck it up and lie anyway always with a smile.

Which brings me back to your second question, did the recruiter know that many of the candidates would lie to him about that?

Yes, I'd say that he did. The thing is. It's better if he finds young people who are willing to pick up trash, even during their lunch time when no one is looking. But if he can't find enough of those young people with that kind of attitude, the second best thing is to find young people who are willing to fake it at the very least and seem compliant enough to want to fake it.

Now, is it a big deal that you didn't lie? No, it isn't. As a young person, failing your first couple of interviews is perfectly normal. It's part of the learning process.

Sometimes, being offered a job can also be a numbers game. So don't be discouraged and apply to many more employers.

Comment: This happened more than10 years ago BTW :)

Comment: That's cool ! I just saw your edit. Hopefully, you were able to find a job during those 10 years. It would suck if you didn't.

Comment: Hehe! Yes, I have had several jobs since then :)

Comment: "Fake it until you make it." Or, you know, see such questions as a red flag. Only work there if you're running out of options. Decent employers ask better questions in a better way.

Comment: Advising lying is immoral. If I had the rep to do so this would get a downvote.

Comment: @Joshua Well, more importantly, it's a bad idea. They want and expect employee to send their lunch hours providing free labor.  Doesn't sound like a good group to work for to me.

Comment: @Joshua, are there any scenario at work where lying would be acceptable to you?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: I know of scenarios where lying is morally acceptable. I know of none where advising it is.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I like to think on the positive side.  I would just assume that they were clumsily telling employees that their lunch break is for eating lunch and they can pick up the trash when they are back on the clock.  If my assumption was right, then all the suck ups would be sent home and I get the job.  If my assumption was wrong, then I would be sent home and a suck up would get the job.  Either way I win.

Answer (score 21):

No, you shouldn't have lied. From your attitude towards picking it up, it's clear that you wouldn't be a good fit for the job - sticking to a rigid definition of your "job role" isn't a good way to get ahead in any job, let alone an entry level service industry job. Better to find that out now than later.

Comment: FWIW, I would do it if specifically instructed to do it by my superiors. But I would not take the initiative to do it myself.

Comment: And that attitude is going to be a real killer for your career prospects long term. *No* employer, in any industry, wants an employee who needs to be micromanaged like that before they'll do what is *clearly* the right thing.

Comment: So you would pick up trash on the side of the road on your lunch break?  If you see a cigarette butt on the ground as you enter your building before work do you pick it up?

Comment: @Paparazzi No, *I* don't pick up litter. But the success of my company isn't particularly dependent on having a spotless environment. I certainly do stuff outside my job description if it *is* important to the success of the company.

Comment: Philip, I don't really think having a spotless environment is that important to the amusement park. There's usually some bits of trash here and there, and as long as it's just a little bit, I don't think the guests care that much. The cleaning personnel *do* of course go constantly around the park to deal with it. The amusement park is full of excited, very active kids, and generally quite noisy and disorderly. I'd argue that as a business, it's on the lower end of the spectrum when it comes to spotlessness being a must. @Paparazzi

Comment: On the other hand, if a food worker was handling old trash from the roadside, *that's* something I would frown upon as a guest.

Comment: So it needs to be more than clearly the right thing - it needs to be  important to the success of the company.   You would not pick up trash at your place of business because is it not what you deem important to the success of the company.  If it is important to the park then they should have a cleaning crew.  I personally would not want to see the same guy that served my girl cotton candy picking up trash.

Comment: Seems your own reasoning imply that the OP should definitely have lied. Surely, if “no employer in any industry“ wants someone who answers no and you want a job, you have to lie.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon in the service and hospitality industries for there to be a big focus on cleanliness, and I'd wager that the park's management considers it more important than you think, because they asked the question. You could also look to the extraordinary lengths Disney, a leader in the industry, takes to keep its parks clean.

Comment: @ZachLipton Good points. It's also relevant, though, that I might be working with food and I'm myself on the way to eat. Sure, I would wash my hands and maybe have a second uniform. But will guests who see me be sure of that?

Comment: I mean, it sounds like you were overthinking the question. I think the exact details and any food handling rules are the kinds of things you could have asked your manager about if you actually had the job. And there's sort of an assumption that we're talking about a piece of litter like a coffee cup and not a giant mess (you could call whoever is in charge of cleaning the park for that). At the interview stage, the point is more: "would you walk by and ignore an obvious problem because you didn't think it was your job to do anything about it?" and no employer wants to hear "yes" to that.

Comment: @ZachLipton Yeah, sure.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you are not looking at this in the right way. You could interpret the question as "We expect our employees to take pride in their working environment and contribute by helping to keep the place tidy. Raise your hand if you understand, and are prepared to do that."

Now you can raise your hand if you are willing to do the job that's expected of you.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you need to do what you believe is right, even if you suspect you might have to bear the consequences.

We all face times when we know that stark honesty might be somewhat costly. We need to weigh in our own minds if that cost is worth being dishonest or not.

You were honest. Hopefully, that honesty worked out for you. Perhaps not in that particular job (which you may not have wanted anyway), but perhaps in another job that met your requirements.

> But I would not take the initiative to do it myself. it's not my job,
>   somebody else are employed to do it. It's my lunch time.

My guess is that this was the whole point of the question.

Some employers want people who care about their job, the company, their surroundings, and who would do good things that aren't technically their job. Some companies want their employees to have initiative. Some companies don't really care as long as you do what you are told.

You felt that picking up trash was beneath you. And you also conveyed that you wouldn't take the initiative to do things (anything?) on your own, but would do what you were explicitly told to do. For some employers, that would be fine - for others, not so much. If you felt strongly about it, then perhaps this wouldn't be a good job for you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The job is in customer service. You are in a uniform. The place you will be working in is the amusement park. Managers expect all their employees to take pride in making sure their customers have a safe, enjoyable stay at the park. They know that once a level of uncleanliness creeps in some customers will not be comfortable.

The expected answer is that you will pick up the trash.

As to the answer they are looking for: no idea. They could be using this  question with a series of other questions as another way to filter the potential employees. And filter may not be hire/No Hire; it could be uniform/no uniform.

The confusing thing is that if the group of applicants was large and the expected answer was for people to raise their hand, they would never know you didn't raise your hand.

Comment: We were divided into groups, and the evaluators would certainly be able to keep track of who raised their hands when. I'm assuming that was the point of the questions. This was the very first stage to filter people out.

Comment: The group evaluation as a whole was the first stage, I mean. I don't remember at what stage of the evaluation those questions came.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what the "right" answer is.  It is possible that the "right" answer is to pick up the trash.  It is also possible that the park has recently gotten in trouble for break violations and the "right" answer is to not pick up the trash.

For perspective here is the [story](http://www.syracuse.com/state/index.ssf/2015/11/east_greenbush_walmart_employee_fired_for_collecting_cans.html) of a man who got fired for picking up trash.

> Smith said he was interrogated by a manager and security staff who
>   told him that collecting garbage and recycling the discarded cans for
>   money was the same as theft of Walmart property.

Don't steal WalMart's precious garbage.

In my opinion, you should use your lunch break for eating lunch and not for picking up garbage.

Comment: This is a great example of [false equivalence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence)

Comment: With that said, it was truly a shame that man was fired for redeeming the deposit on those bottles.  Even more so when you consider that he was fired for "theft" of $5.10 but another person at the same store was NOT fired for stealing a $20 bill from the cash register.  Insanity!

Comment: @Lumberjack I think the actual equivalence here is that the HR departments/practices at both companies are completely abysmal.  So... in that sense, emory's not exactly wrong, either. :)

Comment: @Lumberjack It is not obvious to me what Smith should have done.  In retrospect, the safest course of action for Smith would have been to not "steal" WalMart's $5.10 worth of cans.  If I could go back in time and counsel Smith, I would tell him to not pick up WalMart's trash.

Comment: @HopelessN00b lol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that (like almost everything else in adult life) being employed is about "playing a game according to the rules." Not putting your hand up was a signal that either you don't understand that fact of life, or that you don't understand the rules of the game you want to sign up to.

Objectively, a piece of litter on the ground isn't very important in itself, provided it's not attracting the sort of critters (rats, flies, wasps, whatever) that customers won't want to encounter in an amusement park.

But the management case-study version of this scenario is "aircraft coffee stain syndrome". You book a flight with Cheapskate Airlines. When you get on the plane, you find the tray in front of your seat is covered by the remains of a spilled cup of coffee. Well, that's not a big deal considering how cheap your ticket was. But then you might start thinking "hey, if these people don't bother to check if the inside of the plane is clean, I wonder if they bother to check the important stuff that might kill me if it fails" - or if they check if anybody on the previous flight left a bomb in the overhead lockers".

Exactly the same applies to an amusement park. You don't want the customers to be worrying if this might happen to them...

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/12013930/Alton-Towers-The-Smiler-crash-caused-by-human-error.html